# How can one detect a crawler / spider using PHP?

Tags: php, user-agent

**How can one detect a crawler / spider using PHP?**

I'm currently working on a project where I need to keep track of each crawler's visit.
I know that you should use HTTP_USER_AGENT but I'm not really sure how to format the code for this purpose and i know that the USER AGENT can be changed very easy so **i would also like to know if it is possible to add some more parameters to avoid spoofing?**

Sample code of what i'm trying to do..

```
<?php
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if (strpos( $user_agent, 'Google') !== false)
{
echo "Googlebot is here";
}
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: You can easily find crawlers when you check the Webservers logfiles and look for many requests in short time from a single IP or subnet.

Most search engines do not modify their crawler to act like they were a browser

Comment: That is not true since you could combine the HTTP_USER_AGENT with REMOTE_ADDR, for instance, googlebot always crawl using the hostname googlebot.com. But how i setup a script for this i do not know. Regards Dennis

Comment: If you dont want you page crawled, make use of the robots.txt
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_Exclusion_Standard

At least some crawler respect the robots.txt

Comment: I want the page to be crawled, I just want to keep track of it :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [Verifying Googlebot](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553):

> You can verify that a bot accessing your server really is Googlebot (or another Google user-agent) by using a reverse DNS lookup, verifying that the name is in the googlebot.com domain, and then doing a forward DNS lookup using that googlebot name. This is useful if you're concerned that spammers or other troublemakers are accessing your site while claiming to be Googlebot.

> For example:

> > `host 66.249.66.1`
> > `1.66.249.66.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer` 
> > `crawl-66-249-66-1.googlebot.com.`

> > `host crawl-66-249-66-1.googlebot.com`
> > `crawl-66-249-66-1.googlebot.com has address 66.249.66.1`
> > Google doesn't post a public list of IP addresses for webmasters to whitelist. This is because these IP address ranges can change, causing problems for any webmasters who have hard coded them. The best way to identify accesses by Googlebot is to use the user-agent (Googlebot).

You can do a reverse DNS lookup:

```
function validateGoogleBotIP($ip) {
    $hostname = gethostbyaddr($ip); //"crawl-66-249-66-1.googlebot.com"

    return preg_match('/\.google(bot)?\.com$/i', $hostname);
}

if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Google') !== false) {
    if (validateGoogleBotIP($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
        echo 'It is ACTUALLY google';
    } else {
        echo 'Someone\'s faking it!';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Nothing to do with Google';
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much for taking your time and helping me!

Comment: @Squeeze You're welcome. It should work (if not, your host might not allow DNS lookups). Eg. codepad.org wouldn't let me create a demo of this as it couldn't look up hostnames. That might, however, just be their sandbox.

Comment: I'm currently hosting my website on a VPS so if there is any error with the DNS lookup i got none to blame but my self :p Thank you again :)

Comment: In researching this topic I came across this solution. Easy and simply, thanks - I should mention that Google says the returned hostname can match googlebot.com OR google.com 

"Verify that the domain name is either googlebot.com or google.com."

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/verifying-googlebot

Comment: @LarsKoudal Thank you for pointing this out. I've changed the regex slightly to support both.

Comment: Let's say that I want to detect most search engines, would I need to do what you did with Google bot for all other search engines or is there a faster way?

Comment: @FabianAmran In that case you'd either have to write it for all search engines or use something a little less heavy like [jaybizzle/crawler-detect](https://packagist.org/packages/jaybizzle/crawler-detect) that simply checks the user agent without any verification.

Answer (score 7):

**100% Working on my website** to detect robots, crawlers, spiders and copiers.

```
function isBotDetected() {

    if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) and preg_match('/abacho|accona|AddThis|AdsBot|ahoy|AhrefsBot|AISearchBot|alexa|altavista|anthill|appie|applebot|arale|araneo|AraybOt|ariadne|arks|aspseek|ATN_Worldwide|Atomz|baiduspider|baidu|bbot|bingbot|bing|Bjaaland|BlackWidow|BotLink|bot|boxseabot|bspider|calif|CCBot|ChinaClaw|christcrawler|CMC\/0\.01|combine|confuzzledbot|contaxe|CoolBot|cosmos|crawler|crawlpaper|crawl|curl|cusco|cyberspyder|cydralspider|dataprovider|digger|DIIbot|DotBot|downloadexpress|DragonBot|DuckDuckBot|dwcp|EasouSpider|ebiness|ecollector|elfinbot|esculapio|ESI|esther|eStyle|Ezooms|facebookexternalhit|facebook|facebot|fastcrawler|FatBot|FDSE|FELIX IDE|fetch|fido|find|Firefly|fouineur|Freecrawl|froogle|gammaSpider|gazz|gcreep|geona|Getterrobo-Plus|get|girafabot|golem|googlebot|\-google|grabber|GrabNet|griffon|Gromit|gulliver|gulper|hambot|havIndex|hotwired|htdig|HTTrack|ia_archiver|iajabot|IDBot|Informant|InfoSeek|InfoSpiders|INGRID\/0\.1|inktomi|inspectorwww|Internet Cruiser Robot|irobot|Iron33|JBot|jcrawler|Jeeves|jobo|KDD\-Explorer|KIT\-Fireball|ko_yappo_robot|label\-grabber|larbin|legs|libwww-perl|linkedin|Linkidator|linkwalker|Lockon|logo_gif_crawler|Lycos|m2e|majesticsEO|marvin|mattie|mediafox|mediapartners|MerzScope|MindCrawler|MJ12bot|mod_pagespeed|moget|Motor|msnbot|muncher|muninn|MuscatFerret|MwdSearch|NationalDirectory|naverbot|NEC\-MeshExplorer|NetcraftSurveyAgent|NetScoop|NetSeer|newscan\-online|nil|none|Nutch|ObjectsSearch|Occam|openstat.ru\/Bot|packrat|pageboy|ParaSite|patric|pegasus|perlcrawler|phpdig|piltdownman|Pimptrain|pingdom|pinterest|pjspider|PlumtreeWebAccessor|PortalBSpider|psbot|rambler|Raven|RHCS|RixBot|roadrunner|Robbie|robi|RoboCrawl|robofox|Scooter|Scrubby|Search\-AU|searchprocess|search|SemrushBot|Senrigan|seznambot|Shagseeker|sharp\-info\-agent|sift|SimBot|Site Valet|SiteSucker|skymob|SLCrawler\/2\.0|slurp|snooper|solbot|speedy|spider_monkey|SpiderBot\/1\.0|spiderline|spider|suke|tach_bw|TechBOT|TechnoratiSnoop|templeton|teoma|titin|topiclink|twitterbot|twitter|UdmSearch|Ukonline|UnwindFetchor|URL_Spider_SQL|urlck|urlresolver|Valkyrie libwww\-perl|verticrawl|Victoria|void\-bot|Voyager|VWbot_K|wapspider|WebBandit\/1\.0|webcatcher|WebCopier|WebFindBot|WebLeacher|WebMechanic|WebMoose|webquest|webreaper|webspider|webs|WebWalker|WebZip|wget|whowhere|winona|wlm|WOLP|woriobot|WWWC|XGET|xing|yahoo|YandexBot|YandexMobileBot|yandex|yeti|Zeus/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
    ) {
        return true; // 'Above given bots detected'
    }

    return false;

} // End :: isBotDetected()
```

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] can be manipulated by your visitor at the time of sending the request.

Comment: Yandex has it's Yandex Browser now

Answer (score 0):

To properly validate if a visitor is from a search engine you need more than just checking the User-Agent which can be easily spoofed.

The proper method is to look up the hostname of the IP and do a quick check if it matches any of the hostnames we know search engines crawlers use.

If the hostname matches one of the known crawlers, THEN you look up the IP of the hostname and see if the two are a match. If one of the steps fails, you have a fake search engine crawler visiting.

The following function accepts an IP and follows previously mentioned steps. It identifies Baidu, Bing, Google, Yahoo, and Yandex.

```
 /**
 * Validate a crawlers IP against the hostname 
 * Warning - str_ends_with() requires PHP 8
 *
 * @param   mixed   $ip 
 * @return  boolean
 */
function validate_crawler_ip( $testip ) {
   $hostname = strtolower( gethostbyaddr( $testip ) );
   $valid_host_names = array(
      '.crawl.baidu.com',
      '.crawl.baidu.jp',
      '.google.com',
      '.googlebot.com',
      '.crawl.yahoo.net',
      '.yandex.ru',
      '.yandex.net',
      '.yandex.com',
      '.search.msn.com',
   );
   $valid_ip = false;
   foreach ( $valid_host_names as $valid_host ) {
     // Using string_ends_with() to make sure the match is in the -end- of the hostname (to prevent fake matches)
     if ( str_ends_with( $hostname, $valid_host ) ) { // PHP 8 function
      $returned_ip = gethostbyname( $hostname );        
      if ( $returned_ip === $testip ) {
        // The looked up IP from the host matches the incoming IP - we have validated!
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  // No match - not valid crawler
  return false;
}
```