# PHP Code for Search Engine Bot Detection Like Google Bot

Tags: bots

Looking for a better and affective PHP code to detect Search Engine Bots like google bot,
Please need recommendation the code below is working perfect or any other code that perform much better then this?

```html
function _bot_detected() {
   return (
      isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
      && preg_match('/bot|crawl|slurp|spider|mediapartners/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
}
```

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to detect search engine bots with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677419/how-to-detect-search-engine-bots-with-php)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980363/how-can-one-detect-a-crawler-spider-using-php

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422969/how-to-recognize-bots-with-php