# How to collect page views while excluding bots and crawlers in 2016?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, .net, bots

We want to add page views counters to our articles pages (just like in Stackoverflow), but we don't want to add page views of bots and crawlers.

I searched quite a bit, and only found very obsolete answers which say to fire an AJAX request, since crawlers and bots don't execute javascript...
Well, it's 2016... I believe all the major crawlers execute javascript nowadays.

I thought about two viable solutions:

1. Keep a list of all known bots and crawlers User Agents on the server, and only increase the counter in case the request isn't of one of them (seems like a very bad solution since the list needs to be maintained and updated regularly, and probably there will be many that the list won't catch).
2. Use AJAX to send a request to an endpoint that is disallowed in `robots.txt`. (or a hidden image with a `src="/article/track/?id=xxxxx"`)

The second option creates another request per page, not horrible, but maybe there's a better way? What is the common way of handling this today?

<sub>Using ASP.NET Core and storing the page views in redis if it matters</sub>

Comment: [Example of an obsolete answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17515381/601179)

Comment: Crawlers, AFAIK, track AJAX requests as well, this was essential when one-page apps and dynamic pages were introduced [read more](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more)

Comment: Honeypots seems fine http://security.stackexchange.com/a/17107

Comment: @AdamAzad of course they do track AJAX, this is why I wrote to disallow it in `robots.txt`

Comment: maybe this can help, the hidden link feature sounds good http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11669/what-is-the-best-way-to-exclude-bots-from-view-counts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out how Stackoverflow themselves handle it:

```
<script>
    StackExchange.ready(function(){$.get('/posts/40008735/ivc/e079');});
</script>
<noscript>
    <div>
        <img src="/posts/40008735/ivc/e079" class="dno" alt="" width="0" height="0">
    </div>
</noscript>
```

And in robots.txt:

```
Disallow: /*/ivc/*
...
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /*/ivc/*
```

So basically, they handle it as I suggested in option 2:

Issue an AJAX request (or with a hidden img in case javascript is disabled) and instruct crawlers and bots to not crawl that URL with `Disallow`.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned on chat, you could cache the IP address of the client when it requests `/robots.txt`.

On other requests, check if the IP address is in the cache and don't count it as a page view if it is.

Comment: Thanks, though I decided to go with the solution used by SO.